# Tracking current during iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of posts. I need to generate it each one by one. For generation of each post, I need to know about other posts. However, I want to make the current post marked.

```
def generate(posts):
    print(posts) #faking generation

def marked_active_post(orig_posts, active_index):
    posts_view = orig_posts.copy()
    active_post = orig_posts[active_index]
    active_post = orig_posts[active_index].copy()
    active_post['active?'] = True
    posts_view[active_index] = active_post
    return posts_view

posts = [{'foo':'bar'}, {'aaa':'bbb'}]
for i in range(0, len(posts)):
    generate(marked_active_post(posts, i))
```

How can I do better?

Comment: Created as a more detailed question from http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63174/static-blog-generator

Comment: The loop variable `i` tells you which post is current. So why not use that?

Comment: @Gareth - I can not do any logic in my template engine *(pystache)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's too bad your template engine doesn't support conditions. What about this?

```
def marked_active_post(orig_posts, active_index):
    posts_view = orig_posts.deepcopy()
    posts_view[active_index]['active?'] = True
    return posts_view
```

That means n+1 copies instead of 2, but no need to optimize it until it proves to be slow.

Comment: I don't like this code either. But can not come up with better approach.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very simple point which I'm sure you already know, but I wanted to say it anyway just in case.

You should wrap the main execution like the following:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    posts = [{'foo':'bar'}, {'aaa':'bbb'}]
    for i in range(0, len(posts)):
       generate(marked_active_post(posts, i))
```

This allows you to import your script into other scripts without anything actually running.

Comment: Thank you for mention it. It could be useful for readers.